# How to pass arguments to a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

In the examples I see, the code in a promise is static. An example:

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
  if (true)
    resolve("It is a success!")
  else
    reject(("It is a failure."));
});

promise.then(function (x) {
   alert(x);
}).catch(function (err) {
      alert("Error: " + err);
    });
```

How do I pass arguments to the promise so that useful work can be done?  Is it by the use of global variables?

Comment: right now `alert(x)` would alert("It is a success!"), you can change that string to be whatever you want.

Comment: You can pass an object to the `resolve` callback: `resolve({status: 'success', message: "It is a success!"})`(For example) and in the resolve callback you can access it like `alert(x.message);` or `alert(x.status);`

Comment: Not *global* variables, but usually you'll just use any variables in scope at the time the Promise is created.

Comment: Just as always, put the value you are creating in a function and let it depend on the parameters?! Your question is the same as "How to pass arguments to a string?" or "How to pass arguments to an object literal?".

Comment: What do you consider to be "useful work"?

Comment: Work that depends on some input value, rather than producing the same constant output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it may be done with the following code:

```
function getSomePromise(myVar) {
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    if (myVar)
      resolve("It is a success!")
    else
      reject(("It is a failure."));
  });
  return promise;
}

var variableToPass = true;
getSomePromise(variableToPass).then(function (x) {
  alert(x);
}).catch(function (err) {
  alert("Error: " + err);
});
```

***Update:***

As @AlonEitan suggested, you can simplify `getSomePromise` function:

```
function getSomePromise(myVar) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
    if (myVar)
      resolve("It is a success!")
    else
      reject(("It is a failure."));
  });
}
```

Comment: You can just `return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {`

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, i agree